# Create validation sampels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am currently training my neural network. Unfortunately I forgot to reserve several samples for validation. How can I incorporate this?

I have a dok matrix that creates a sparisty matrix and then converts the data with `get_train_sampels()`. How can I now incorporate the validation sampelsfor my code?

**Example** from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate:

```
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]
.
.
.
print("Fit model on training data")
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    # We pass some validation for
    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
    # at the end of each epoch
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

**My Code:**

```
def get_train_samples(train_mat, num_negatives):
    user_input, item_input, labels = [], [], []
    num_user, num_item = train_mat.shape
    for (u, i) in train_mat.keys():
        user_input.append(u)
        item_input.append(i)
        labels.append(1)
        # negative instances
        for t in range(num_negatives):
            j = np.random.randint(num_item)
            while (u, j) in train_mat.keys():
                j = np.random.randint(num_item)
            user_input.append(u)
            item_input.append(j)
            labels.append(0)
    return user_input, item_input, labels
.
.
.
train_mat = sp.load_npz('matrix.npz')
num_users, num_items = train_mat.shape
.
.
.
model = get_model(num_users, num_items, latent_dim, dense_layers, reg_layers, reg_mf[0])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
user_input, item_input, labels = get_train_samples(train_mat, num_negatives)

hist = model.fit([np.array(user_input), np.array(item_input)], np.array(labels)
                 , epochs=epochs, verbose=verbose, shuffle=True, batch_size = batch_size)
```

---

**Edit**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
train_mat = sp.load_npz('matrix.npz')
val_mat = train_mat[-10000:]
train_mat = train_mat[:-10000]

num_users, num_items = train_mat.shape
.
.
.
model = get_model(num_users, num_items, latent_dim, dense_layers, reg_layers, reg_mf[0])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
user_input, item_input, labels = get_train_samples(train_mat, num_negatives)
val_user_input, val_item_input, val_labels = get_train_samples(train_mat, num_negatives)

hist = model.fit([np.array(user_input), np.array(item_input)], 
  np.array(labels), 
  epochs=epochs, 
  verbose=verbose, 
  validation_data=([np.array(val_user_input), np.array(val_item_input)], 
  np.array(val_labels)),
  shuffle=True, batch_size = batch_size)
```

You have to restart training. Otherwise your valuation loss may not show overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Unfortunately, the verbose still doesn't show the validation_loss?

Comment: try to set verbose=1

Comment: [Why val_loss and val_acc are not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746382/why-val-loss-and-val-acc-are-not-displaying) `Validation loss and accuracy are computed on epoch end`